# "Diagonalisation" of second order linear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-pde

Define the operator
$$
Pu=\sum_{ij} a_{ij}(x) \partial^2_{ij} u+\sum_k b_k(x) \partial_k u+c(x) u.
$$
My question is, in what situation can we somehow "diagonalise" the principle part of $P$, namely $\sum_{ij} a_{ij}(x) \partial^2_{ij} u$?

That is, to find a system of coordinates $y_i$ such that
$$
\sum_{ij} a_{ij}(x) \partial^2_{ij} u= \sum_{k} \lambda_k(x) \partial^2_{y_k\space y_k} u+\text{lower order derivatives of }u
$$

I find that, although this is quite easy for constant $a_{ij}$, it is very difficult in the general case, since differentiaing leads to extra terms according to chain rule, when changing the coordinates.

I am just wondering if there exists an "appropriate" way of "diagonalising" the principle part, or to find a "canonical form".

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation) article it is possible for two dimensional elliptic pdes but in higher dimensions it is in general not possible.

Comment: So could you find a proof of this?

Comment: One needs to find a counter example in 3 dimensions. For that you have to calculate all the additional terms that arise for a coordinate transformation via the chain rule. Then you get a system of equations for which you have to show that it is non solvable. However, in three dimensions this gets quite messy and is not an easy thing to do.